# Sort UItableView section by date conditional

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, ios5, tableview

Having myArray (`NSMutableArray`) as `dataSource` with events

And the custom table sections are:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    customSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //My custom sections
    [customSections addObject:@"now"];
    [customSections addObject:@"in this day"];

    NSString *sectionText = [customSections objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionText;   
}
```

What's the best practice to short them?
for each event I have a start time and end time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize and fill in your customSections array somewhere in another place (for example when you initializing this class). Than you have to do something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [customSections count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [customSections objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Comment: Let me give you an example, maybe it will be more clear:
myArray its a NSMutableArray with events;
firstSection will include ONLY events that are happening now and the 2nd one lets say today events...

Comment: Try to understand how tableView works. TableView will ask it's dataSource for number of sections (`numberOfSectionsInTableView:`), than it will ask dataSource for each section's title (`tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`) and in this method you will get number of section. Depending on this number you will return appropriate title for section. Also tableView will ask dataSource for number of rows in each section (`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`). And finally tableView will ask dataSource for cell in specific section at specific row (`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`).

Comment: like Apple's [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) but for me with just two custom sections

Comment: ok. what you didn't understand from my post and comment? If you would like 2 sections than you should return `2` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method as I wrote before...

Comment: sorry for not being so clear; I know how to specify the number of sections in a tableView; what I don't know for sure how to have events happening now in first section and events happening today in 2nd one...

Comment: create 2 arrays, one for each type of events. When you load your controller fill in both arrays with appropriate objects. In method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return count of appropriate array's elements depending on section. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return cell with some data (text, image...) from appropriate array (depending on section).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4838/discussion-between-el-severo-and-yas375)